# Do C/C++ have standard 'slice' container?

Tags: c++, c

I often use a slice structure in my projects:

```
struct SSlice {
    void *pData;
    size_t length;
};
```

Also I see other projects use similar containers to work with data w/o copying it (like RocksDB, MDB, etc...). Do anybody knows is there a standard (or OS-related) header with such container?
In STL, linux headers, no matter.

UPD. Main purpose of such container in my and mentioned projects is to work with data w/o copying it. E.g. I use it to parse URI path or LDAP DN and represent it as vector of slices.

Comment: The [Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) recommend the existence of a `span` template that achieves this.

Comment: `C/C++` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you
see.

Comment: Any STL container such as `std::vector` does that **if** you use `std::move` correctly. Even if not you can just use a pointer to a container to achieve the effect of "working with data without copying it". I think you need to be more specific in what you want to achieve.

Comment: @nwp You cannot move from an `std::vector` into another type, unless the type already handles such a move constructor in its design. And even then, `std::vector` cannot release its buffer, therefore external classes cannot move from an `std::vector`

Comment: There is always [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) and it be available as a TS.

Comment: There will also be `string_view` soon. And there is postponed `array_view` which is avaliable in GSL.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more typical in C++ standard library, to use a range of iterators (begin, end), rather than an iterator and length (begin, length). Pointers are a case of iterator, which is a more general concept.

There exist no standard structure for ranges, nor slices<sup>†</sup> that you describe. The standard interfaces treat the begin and end as separate objects.

However, addition of ranges has been [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html) and there exists a [technical specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf), that may already be supported by some standard library implementations.

<sup>†</sup> At least, not in general, but there is the special `std::valarray` container which provides a [slice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice) interface to its contents.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string_view` is a C++17 non-owning view of a range of characters with `std::string`-like functionality.  It is intended to speed oarsing, among other things.

`span` and `array_view` are names for various standarization and proto-standization efforts that also match your concept, but are not string-presuming.